# Is it possible to block Outgoing SMS?

Tags: android, android-manifest

Here is the Code which I am using,

```
public class MyCallControllerActivity extends Activity 
{
    static int Count;
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 CheckBox blockAll_cb;//,blockcontacts_cb;
 BroadcastReceiver CallBlocker;

 TelephonyManager telephonyManager;


@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 initviews();

 CallBlocker =new BroadcastReceiver()
 {


@Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
 {
     Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
     //Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();


        if ( bundle != null )
        {
           // do you manipulation on String then if you can abort.


        }

        Object messages[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage smsMessage[] = new SmsMessage[messages.length];

        for (int n = 0; n <messages.length; n++) 
        {
        smsMessage[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
        }
        if("+919739036754".equalsIgnoreCase(smsMessage[0].getOriginatingAddress()))
        {
            //abortBroadcast();
            String Body=smsMessage[0].getMessageBody();
            if (Body.startsWith("START"))
            {
                Toast toast6 = Toast.makeText(context,"There is START ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);toast6.show(); 

            }
            else
            {
                setResultData(null);
                setResultCode(0);
                abortBroadcast();
            }
        }
        else
        {


        }
        // show first message
        Toast toast1= Toast.makeText(context,"Sent SMS: " + smsMessage[0].getOriginatingAddress()+ "\nBody: "+smsMessage[0].getMessageBody(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast1.show(); 

 }
 };//BroadcastReceiver
 IntentFilter filter= new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT");
 registerReceiver(CallBlocker, filter);




}



 public void initviews()
 {
 blockAll_cb=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbBlockAll);

 }
 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onDestroy();
 if (CallBlocker != null)
 {
 unregisterReceiver(CallBlocker);
 CallBlocker = null;
 }
```

Here is the Manifest,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.block"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.block.MyCallControllerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT" />                   
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: you cannot check this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/-nWtlbOVyTA

Comment: @SankarV Yes right, you actually cannot check that thread because it is banned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot block the Outgoing SMS from the default Message application because there is no Broadcast for Outgoing Text Messages.

A Simple Google search will reveal [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=block%20outgoing%20sms%20android%20programmatically)

Answer (score 2):

I make it work but only with rooted device with permission MODIFY_PHONE_STATE

```
public class OutgoingSMSReceiver extends Service
{

private static final String CONTENT_SMS = "content://sms/";
static String messageId = "";

private class MyContentObserver extends ContentObserver
{

    Context context;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private String phoneNumberBlocked;

    public MyContentObserver(Context context) {
        super(null);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange)
    {
        super.onChange(selfChange);

        prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("com.example.testcall", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        phoneNumberBlocked = prefs.getString("numero", "");

        Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse(CONTENT_SMS);
        Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);

        if (cur.moveToNext())
        {
            String message_id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            String type = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("type"));
            String numeroTelephone=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address")).trim();

            if (numeroTelephone.equals(phoneNumberBlocked))
            {
                if (cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("type")).equals("6"))
                {                       
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put("type", "5");
                    context.getContentResolver().update(uriSMSURI,values,"_id= "+message_id,null);                          
                }
                else if(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("type")).equals("5"))
                {                           context.getContentResolver().delete(uriSMSURI,"_id=?",new String[] { message_id});                      
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications()
    {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    MyContentObserver contentObserver = new MyContentObserver(getApplicationContext());
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getBaseContext().getContentResolver();
    contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse(CONTENT_SMS), true, contentObserver);

}

}

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
```